# heroku login issue when calling command heroku login in my terminal

Tags: heroku

I was trying to to open calling command heroku login but when i type o to open browser it prints error:
Code: ENETUNREACH

$ heroku login
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit:
Code: ENETUNREACH

1. I had successfully created heroku account and loggedin successfilly in my browser but when I trying calling command heroku login in my terminal l got that error that Code:ENETUNREACH